# Launcher.LaunchUriAsync() fails when DisplayApplicationPicker = false

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I'm trying to launch a PDF in the users default PDF reader:

```
public async void NoPicker()
{
    var options = new LauncherOptions() { ContentType = "application/pdf" };

    await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("http://bitcoin.org/bitcoin.pdf"), options);
}
```

This works fine when the default reader is Foxit, but fails for IE and Edge.

However, if I call LaunchUriAsync with DisplayApplicationPicker set, and select IE or Edge  in the application picker it gets launched without any problem:

```
public async void WithPicker()
{
   var options = new LauncherOptions() { ContentType = "application/pdf", DisplayApplicationPicker = true};

   await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("http://bitcoin.org/bitcoin.pdf"), options);
}
```

Why does the behavior of LaunchUriAsync change depending on if the reader is launched with a picker, and is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

After a few test and investigation, I found this problem is related to the [ContentType property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.launcheroptions.contenttype.aspx), seems that the `ContentType = "application/pdf"` type can't associate your URI pointing to a resource on the network. But windows will attempt to use the file type computed from the content type to select the app to launch, so it opens Edge, but it doesn't point to your URI. You can also refer to [ContentType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn554291.aspx), there is no such pdf content type.

I don't know why Foxit can work in this situation, so this problem is possible also related to the reader you used.

To solve this problem, you can just modify your code like this:

```
public async void NoPicker()
{
    var options = new LauncherOptions();
    await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("http://bitcoin.org/bitcoin.pdf"), options);
}
```

When default browser is Edge or Chrome, it will directly open up this pdf file, but when using IE, it will open an user interface(UI) to let user choose to download this file.

To confirm my conclusion about `ContentType`, you can change it to different types to test, for example you can test `options.ContentType = "application/x-compress";`, it will make it behavior like it is set `DisplayApplicationPicker = true`.